# Not able to access value of variable derived from google distance matrix function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

I am using Google distance matrix api to get the distance between two locations. I declared a variable globally. Changed this variable in function. But as per normal circumstances I should be able to access this changed value of variable after calling my function. But now I am not being able to access the changed value of variable. My code is:

```
var distance = require('google-distance-matrix');

var origins = ['San Francisco CA'];
var destinations = ['New York NY'];

distance.key('My API key');
distance.units('imperial');
// my global variabel
let ourdistance;

function getdistance(){ distance.matrix(origins, destinations, function (err, distances) {
     for (var i=0; i < origins.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < destinations.length; j++) {
                var origin = distances.origin_addresses[i];
                var destination = distances.destination_addresses[j];
                if (distances.rows[0].elements[j].status == 'OK') {
                    var distance = distances.rows[i].elements[j].distance.text;
                    console.log("This is the distance covered "+ distance);
                    //changing global variable value inside function
                    ourdistance=distance}}}});}

// calling function                    
getdistance();

console.log("finale distance is "+ ourdistance);
```

Result that I got is:----
"finale distance is undefined"
"This is the distance covered 2,903 mi"

Now I don't know that why  "This is the distance covered 2,903 mi" is coming first and why I can't get the changed value of variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. `console.log("finale distance is "+ ourdistance);` is executing before `getdistance()` is finished.
So, you have to `console.log` inside the callback.

Example:

```
async function main() {
  const util = require('util');
  const matrix = util.promisify(distance.matrix);

  async function getdistance() {
    let ourdistance;
    const distances = await matrix(origins, destinations);
    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < destinations.length; j++) {
        var origin = distances.origin_addresses[i];
        var destination = distances.destination_addresses[j];
        if (distances.rows[0].elements[j].status == 'OK') {
          var distance = distances.rows[i].elements[j].distance.text;
          console.log("This is the distance covered " + distance);
          ourdistance = distance
        }
      }
    }

    return ourdistance;
  }

  // calling function                    
  let ourdistance = await getdistance();

  console.log("finale distance is " + ourdistance);
}

main();
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply but I want the value of distance outside this call back function. Is there any way that I can get this.

Comment: Yes there is a workaround. Let me update the answer.